# Fullscreen the window on the all of the screens

Tags: electron

I am new with the ElectronJS and sorry for being not be smart with these staffs yet.
I am trying to make a login page for my future company but first I need to prepare everything to able to start something.
So if someone is turn on the computer then they need to use the windows login and when logged in then my application will appear and asking for the specific pin code.

Big story, in short I need to make the application to hide the desktop on all of the screens.

I did this way in C# (because I started to do in C# the project and then I found this ElectronJS and changed my mind to use this instead):

```
private static Rectangle GetDesktopBounds(Form main)
        {
            Rectangle result = new Rectangle();
        for (int i = 0; i < Screen.AllScreens.Length; i++)
            {
            Screen screen = Screen.AllScreens[i];
            result = Rectangle.Union(result, screen.Bounds);
        }

        main.Top = result.Top;
        main.Left = result.Left;
        main.Width = result.Width;
        main.Height = result.Height;
        return result;
    }
```

It works fine in C# but I need in ElectronJS and I did try to make something like this:

```
    let x;
  let y;
  for (let i = 0; i < screen.getAllDisplays().length; i++) {
    x += screen.getAllDisplays()[i].bounds.width;
    
    console.log(screen.getAllDisplays()[i].bounds.width);
    y += screen.getAllDisplays()[i].bounds.height;
    console.log(screen.getAllDisplays()[i].bounds.height);
  }
```

And then:

```
win.setSize(x, y, false);
```

But it doesn't put the window to all of the screens to fullscreen. It does only in the primary screen. If I console log the x and y then I get the NaN message.

So the question is: How I can make the window in fullscreen and put on all of the screens same time?

Thank you for the answers in advance.

Comment: Does this need to work for a double monitor setup?

Comment: Well some coworkers will having different screen setup. Server monitoring is more than 10 screens. Therefore I need to make the app to able to hide all of the screens while it is in fullscreen. 
Therefore I did think to detect first which screens are connected and then put on every screen the window to hide the desktop until the person is writing the right pin code.

I did think to expand the window to other screens but it was not a good idea, then I did think to opening the window in every screens one by one but the instance the same. I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Alright.
I found a solution. maybe not the perfect but works fine for me:

```
    let displays = screen.getAllDisplays()
  let externalDisplay = displays.map(function (display, index, displays) {
    win = new BrowserWindow(
      {
        x: display.bounds.x,
        y: display.bounds.y,
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        fullscreen: true,
        backgroundColor: "#363636",
        frame: false,
        enableLargerThanScreen: true,
        skipTaskbar: true,
        disableAutoHideCursor: false
      }
    );
  })
```